# System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1<Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationCollection> does not contain a definition for IsCompleted

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to use MediaCapture class for a windows 8 desktop app.

I've added references to:

- System.Runtime.dll
- System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
- System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
- System.Threading
- System.Threading.Tasks

My method:

```
public async Task<bool> StartWebCamAsync()
{
    MediaCapture capture = new MediaCapture();
    var  devices = await  DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
    if (0 == devices.Count)
    {                
        return false;
    }                       

    return true;
}
```

So I am not sure, why do I get this error:

> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1'
>   does not contain a definition for 'IsCompleted'

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Another async operations don't give me errors in the same method.

Comment: Is this a run-time or compile time error?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov This is compile error

Comment: I'd go with clean and re-build. If that doesn't work, perhaps a VS restart.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov did not help...

Comment: can you specify what `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync` returns?

Comment: @MarcGravell it gives me compile time error. It should return all avaliable cameras

Comment: Yes, but what type is it?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov type of the return value is DeviceInformationCollection. I think something wrong with this class, because other async operations do not give we any errors...

Comment: @Sasha Add `Windows.Devices.Enumeration` and `Windows.Foundation` to your references and try again.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have them, sorry, that I didn't mentioned that. Can be problem in project type (wpf) or vs version?

Comment: What project did you create?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96230/discussion-between-sasha-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: There is something weird about your project, but there's no practical way for Stack Overflow to know what that is. The `MediaCapture` class is supported for desktop programs. The error you're getting suggests a conflict between the regular desktop API support for `await` and that from Winrt. Other posts mentioning the same error include suggestions to add `System.Threading` and `System.Threading.Tasks` references, but you say you already did that. Maybe the `using` directives are wrong, either one's missing or you have one you shouldn't, causing the wrong extension methods to be used.